# How can i display the values in a progress bar.

Tags: groovy, progress-bar, vaadin

I am using a Vaadin progress bar running with the version 7.6.3. I have used a float value to the progress-bar in order to attain the result. Is there any way to show the values as labels in the progress bar, how much is finished and how much is remaining ?. I have uses .scss script. I need to display in the bar.

```
.v-progressbar-fat .v-progressbar-wrapper {
    height: 60px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the caption of the progress bar each time you change its value to show the progress.

Comment: Yes that is possible, but the caption is always above the progress-bar  to the left. I need the value to be displayed in center of the bar

Comment: @user9630935 You could try adding a label and use CSS to place it in the middle of the bar

Comment: Yes i thought of doing the same. But i have my progress bar in a horizontal layout. So i cannot add any other upon it.